# JavaFX - nested lists in combobox

Tags: listview, binding, combobox, javafx, nested-lists

How do I bind a list of supervisors with nested employees to a single combobox in JavaFX 8.

I have the following simple class structure with employees and supervisors:

```
public class Employee 
{
    private final StringProperty nameProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public Employee(String name)
    {
        this.nameProperty.set(name);
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty()
    {
        return this.nameProperty;
    }
}

public class Supervisor 
{
    private final StringProperty nameProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final ListProperty<Employee> employeesProperty = new SimpleListProperty<Employee>();

    public Supervisor(String name, List<Employee> employees)
    {
        this.nameProperty.set(name);
        this.employeesProperty.addAll(employees);
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty()
    {
        return this.nameProperty;
    }

    public ListProperty<Employee> employeesProperty()
    {
        return this.employeesProperty;
    }
}
```

and finally a simple static Supervisors class:

```
public static class Supervisors
{
    private static final ListProperty<Supervisor> supervisorsProperty = new SimpleListProperty<Supervisor>();

    public static ListProperty<Supervisor> supervisorsProperty()
    {
        return supervisorsProperty;
    }
}
```

(The code has been simplified for this example)

Now, my question is:

How do I bind the list of supervisors to a JavaFX combobox (or listview, the difference shouldn't matter)? I would like to "unfold" the list of employees, so that the combobox items would look  like this:

```
Supervisor A
Employee A.1
Employee A.2
Supervisor B
Employee B.1
```

If I just bind the combobox.itemsProperty to the Supervisors.supervisorsProperty, then I would just get the list of supervisors, not the employees.

Note: I am using a binding, so the adding or removing supervisors or employees would be reflected directly in the combobox.

Do I use a special binding or use some kind a adapter class to "unfold" the nested lists into a single list of supervisors and employees? If the latter, then how do I keep track of changes to the supervisors list (and nested employees), and how do I keep it from becoming a complex mess of changelisteners being registered and unregistered?

PS: There a magic unicorn bonus points if the answer includes a way of always having the correct name of the supervisor/employee displayed in the combobox - so that if a name is changed, then the name is also changed in the combobox.

Comment: Are you looking for Supervisor and Employee in the same ComboBox ?

Comment: Yes. I would probably need a shared base _Person_ class for both Supervisor and Employee that had the name property in it, so it would be ComboBox<Person> - but my headache is really, how do I make a binding (in a nice and clean way, if possible) between the combobox and the list of supervisors and nested employees? Is there a simple way of doing this, or do I need to "unfold" that list into a flat Persons list and then bind to that? (this seems more complex than it needs to be, and I have to think about keeping that flat list up-to-date)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up making the awful and complex solution myself.

I added a base class for both Supervisor and Employee:

```
public abstract class NamedInstance {
    private final StringProperty nameProperty = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public NamedInstance(String name)
    {
        this.nameProperty.set(name);
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty()
    {
        return nameProperty;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return nameProperty.get();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
}
```

The toString() will automatically be used in the ComboBox list.

I then added this awful adapter class for making a flat list version of the nested "supervisor with employees" structure. The flat list will automatically change when supervisors or employees are added or removed from the nested list:

```
public class SupervisorsAndEmployeesList
{
    // the flat list of supervisors and employees
    private final ListProperty<NamedInstance> supervisorsAndEmployees = new SimpleListProperty<NamedInstance>(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
    // a ChangeListener for changes in a list of Employees
    private final ChangeListener<ObservableList<Employee>> employeeChangeListener = new ChangeListener<ObservableList<Employee>>()
    {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends ObservableList<Employee>> observable,
                ObservableList<Employee> oldValue, ObservableList<Employee> newValue) 
        {
            refreshList();
        }

    };

    public SupervisorsAndEmployeesList()
    {
        // add a ChangeListener for changes in the list of Supervisors
        Supervisors.supervisorsProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<ObservableList<Supervisor>>() 
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(
                    ObservableValue<? extends ObservableList<Supervisor>> observable,
                    ObservableList<Supervisor> oldValue,
                    ObservableList<Supervisor> newValue)
            {
                // make sure to have listeners on each employee, and to remove the listeners 
                // again when supervisors are removed
                for (Supervisor supervisor : oldValue)
                {
                    supervisor.employeesProperty().removeListener(employeeChangeListener);
                }
                for (Supervisor supervisor : newValue)
                {
                    supervisor.employeesProperty().addListener(employeeChangeListener);
                }
                refreshList();
            }
        });
    }

    private void refreshList() 
    {
        // clear the list and re-add all Supervisors and Employees. 
        // this is not effective, but more readable than keeping track 
        // a each change in the list
        supervisorsAndEmployees.clear();
        for (Supervisor supervisor : Supervisors.supervisorsProperty().get())
        {
            supervisorsAndEmployees.add(supervisor);
            for (Employee employee : supervisor.employeesProperty().get())
            {
                supervisorsAndEmployees.add(employee);
            }
        }
    }

    public ListProperty<NamedInstance> supervisorsAndEmployeesProperty()
    {
        return supervisorsAndEmployees;
    }
}
```

The ComboBox items is set like this:

```
supervisorsAndEmployeesComboBox.setItems(new SupervisorsAndEmployeesList().supervisorsAndEmployeesProperty().get());
```

An awful lot of code to handle such a task...

I also fixed the issue with having the name in the ComboBox change whenever then Supervisor or Employee name change, but I did not include that code in the above, because it would make the code even more complex and unreadable. Generally though, you "just" add a "nameChangeListener" to the nameProperty of each Supervisor and Employee (remember to also remove the listener as I do with the employeeChangeListener). Each time the nameChangeListener is invoked, you call "refreshList()".